# solving coupled nonlinear ODEs numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a set of ODEs describing a reaction-diffusion system $aA + bB \to cC  $, where $a, b,c$ are stoichiometric coefficients of $A,B,C$ species where $A$ is diffusing and $B,C$ are non-diffusing (static) species. The concentrations of the species are denoted by the same variables $A,B,C$; $k$ is the reaction rate constant and the reaction is elementary. The diffusion coefficient $D_A$ is a function of the concentrations of the static species. The set of ODEs describing my system:

$ 0 = \frac{\partial}{ \partial z}\left(D_A \frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\right) - a k A^a B^b,\\ 
\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = -b k A^a B^b ,\\
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = c k A^a B^b,$

subject to appropriate initial and boundary conditions. I have simplified my system here to a single reaction. My actual system consists of more than one reaction, and more than 3 species. There is quasi-steady diffusion; however time derivatives appear in the governing equations for the static species. What is the best approach  to solve this problem numerically? I  have attempted to solve by finding the quasi-steady profile of $A$ at each time-level and then solving the ODEs for $B,C$ at the respective time-level before proceeding to the next time-level (I have used Newton iteration to handle the nonlinearity and an appropriate second-order finite difference scheme), but this approach seems to fail for certain parameter values.

Comment: Why have you dropped the $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$ term? Are you sure that for this certain parameter values the solution indeed has a quasi-steady profile of $A$?

Comment: @uranix Yes. The concentration of $B,C$ changes on a longer timescale, and that of $A$ changes on a shorter timescale. Therefore I have quasi-steady diffusion of $A$.